# Unable to correctly visualize vector map on Google Map using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am unbale to draw vector layer on google base layer. Geometry is getting displayed but in wrong place.

unable to find out where I am making mistake.

```
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    projection: "EPSG:900913",
    displayProjection: "EPSG:4326",
    numZoomLevels: 18,
    // approximately match Google's zoom animation
    zoomDuration: 10
    });
    var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
"Google Physical",
{
    type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
}
);
    var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
"Google Streets", // the default
{
    numZoomLevels: 20
}
);
   var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
"Google Hybrid",
{
    type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, 
    numZoomLevels: 20
}
);
   var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
"Google Satellite",
{
    type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, 
    numZoomLevels: 22
}
);

   var veroad = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
key: apiKey,
type: "Road",
wrapDateLine: true
 });
     var veaer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
key: apiKey,
type: "Aerial",
wrapDateLine: true
 });
     var vehyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
key: apiKey,
type: "AerialWithLabels",
wrapDateLine: true
});
map.addLayers([gphy, gmap, gsat, ghyb, veroad, veaer, vehyb]);

    var featurecollection = {
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[{
        "type":"Feature",
        "id":"Kalamboli_WaterShed.1",
        "geometry":{
            "type":"MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates":[[[[300741.34931524785,2106906.049050181],[300800.297410894,2106869.2064904],[300854.82439936633,2106879.522407138],[300894.6143639288,2106923.733478872],[300916.71989979583,2106985.6289793015],[300971.3287606237,2107048.01571386],[301068.26562901965,2106953.698760827],[301073.5054597443,2106854.1419770676],[301159.6965815367,2106888.733047083],[301190.6443317514,2106913.049136536],[301885.00284087984,2106978.9788472815],[301886.5673019919,2106702.0692305285],[301975.74158535345,2106620.7172527253],[302216.66859653953,2106608.201563831],[302847.0406657621,2105080.3918409823],[302834.3537288213,2105033.471545858],[302804.6278275608,2104987.8335445123],[302782.2459724944,2104945.8675662656],[302768.2573130804,2104912.6445001513],[302750.42177232413,2104851.4441152085],[302739.5805612759,2104799.336358886],[302713.7015413577,2104715.7541188705],[302682.22705767123,2104601.396828147],[302669.63726419705,2104559.4308498986],[302652.1514399246,2104522.7106189323],[302620.8518144834,2104473.983455298],[302911.02858657064,2104494.4987160494],[303166.90489282465,2104587.207522663],[303348.61415378656,2104687.3330338066],[303467.28142625175,2104750.3750223033],[303537.7401192787,2104772.6251358897],[303604.4904600406,2104798.5836017416],[303645.2823349485,2104802.291954007],[303674.94915306533,2104780.04184042],[303708.32432344736,2104650.249511162],[303726.8660847687,2104550.124000018],[303752.82455062045,2104461.1235456695],[303721.25547322724,2104332.343132814],[303681.1521592293,2104292.3371697706],[303568.1483750431,2104266.139670791],[303486.2609467144,2104266.387994156],[303399.9845870565,2104164.7430431442],[303310.94429402595,2104151.101824263],[303318.84218235145,2104075.114664294],[303139.73065859167,2103975.6159268403],[302969.370562064,2103971.468935796],[302910.03764158604,2103923.7713569934],[302843.5525206531,2103927.928017655],[302642.73793877766,2103725.1470204643],[302622.9902879295,2103630.7781708725],[302463.65661495016,2103564.3766412735],[302344.7708120131,2103550.991090971],[302410.73991494486,2103601.8569815825],[302402.96563938755,2103735.5879491367],[302215.898252468,2103906.623944966],[302182.7263426876,2103936.9530724357],[302140.67819922237,2103853.633953094],[302109.13706720254,2103791.1346576097],[302063.6416661853,2103642.7365233265],[302048.9304914775,2103577.46374962],[302033.2046446043,2103507.688924383],[301977.0560143081,2103397.946618077],[301855.66263330856,2103262.630732585],[301431.3653230744,2103521.435677794],[301099.47130684555,2103708.791487609],[300733.7662491486,2103902.411464472],[300611.74919466034,2105664.3992876173],[299655.4773569257,2105653.8054204835],[299491.1439516857,2105650.7918029223],[299438.09066560393,2105644.896993356],[298699.76576763735,2105599.2122192313],[298627.5543504696,2105641.9495885745],[298571.9741584952,2105654.543904631],[298676.4228154672,2105854.1154456325],[298740.4597896832,2105971.6201847256],[298805.7402002885,2106079.1774326786],[298837.7586873987,2106123.319424618],[298871.52040198125,2106163.4155547996],[298903.35898980626,2106198.007490709],[298967.400150293,2106246.4793260694],[299031.22988511116,2106289.5851210104],[299090.0398211543,2106326.796106385],[299150.46161919547,2106366.586070948],[299323.13041602453,2106457.955619197],[299475.08550702373,2106562.752233681],[299526.27944528457,2106597.5641116975],[299564.1200038132,2106420.6942082513],[299823.3748386969,2106429.817319579],[299831.43818486616,2106467.9077479634],[299794.38145109516,2106586.407852658],[300180.36001105653,2106613.9735865295],[300122.5429216284,2106804.2326380094],[300323.03748841916,2106795.59721148],[300484.02450328256,2106817.4631620017],[300423.47747612034,2106949.7176301945],[300405.42704242177,2107021.8165602386],[300438.1759844469,2107021.816560241],[300716.29637459974,2107057.840396469],[300698.8575629709,2107003.477152708],[300714.5770551426,2106951.078845466],[300741.34931524785,2106906.049050181]]]]
            },
        "geometry_name":"the_geom",
        "properties":{
            "Id":0,
            "POLYGID":0,
            "AREA_Sqkm":8.57423854729,
            "PERIMTR_km":17.697620716,
            "xCentroid":301364.654690385,
            "yCentroid":2105318.17434779,
            "bbox":[298571.9741584952,2103262.630732585,303752.82455062045,2107057.840396469]
            }
        }],
"crs":{
    "type":"EPSG",
    "properties":{
        "code":"900913"
    }
},
 "bbox":[298571.9741584952,2103262.630732585,303752.82455062045,2107057.840396469]
 };

 var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(); 
 var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON",{        
 format: geojson_format
 }); 

 map.addLayer(vector_layer);
 vector_layer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(featurecollection));
```

The GeoJSON layer is in EPSG:900913 projection.